# Virtual box lost files

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macbook, macbook-pro

I have been running Virtual Box on a Macbook Pro for a year or more, with an old version of Windows XP running on the virtual machine.

Recently my Mac battery dies completely and I had left VB / Windows running. When I re-started the Mac, VB would not load.  I reinstalled a recent download of VB from a DMG file I had stored. Now VB starts but when I try to start the virtual machine I get the following message,

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP.
>
> Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WRITE_NON_SYS_GROUP).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component: Console
> Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}

I have been backing up the MAC using Time Machine and have backups going back months.  I really need to access the windows files as they have my Accounts and other business critical stuff.

Any ideas please, or does anyone know where I can get some support for this combination of hardware / software, apologies I am a novice in this area.  Thanks in advance.